# Код работает, если ввести в консоль, но не работает из листинга кода.

Tags: jquery, javascript

Сабж, вот такой вот код... Пробовал сувать и в середину страницы, и в хеад, и в конец... Не работает. Но если ввести тоже самое в консоль (ес-сно без тега script) - то всё работает.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').click(function( e ) {
        alert('Something');
     });
  });
</script>
```

Что делать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Элементы ``.box`` у вас генерируются на сервере или добавляются уже у клиента? Может ``live`` вместо ``click``?

Comment: И вам спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(document).on('click','.box',function( e ) {
        alert('Something');
     });
```

Или проще(но хуже):

```
$('.box').live('click',function( e ) {
        alert('Something');
     });
```

Попробуйте так.
Скорее всего, box у вас появляется при помощи яваскрипта, соответственно, на этапе создания ее еще нет.

Comment: Да, вы правы, на этапе создания ещё нет. Код грузится аяксом. С live заработает?

Comment: Да, заработает. Но live медленнее. Если действий больше сотни, лучше используйте on

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.